# Using openssl with IronPython on a hosted website

Tags: asp.net, python, openssl, ironpython, m2crypto

I have a python script which calls the following:

```
signature = Popen(["openssl", "sha1", "-sign", key, input], stdout=PIPE).stdout.read();
```

I need to run this script through IronPython on a hosted website. Is it possible to use openssl and somehow reference it?

I looked into an alternative using M2Crypto but unfortunately it uses a pyo file which isn't supported with IronPython.

Any help appreciated. Pulling my hair out...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if [.NET's crypto libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) can do what you need, but that's always an option with IronPython.

Otherwise, you should be able to install OpenSSL on Windows and use the code you gave as-is.